# Averaging every 4 entries along the 3rd dimension

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, average, mean

How can I average every 4 data points along the 3rd dimension of a matrix?

My matrix is 245x85x1460 (lonxlatxhour). Since the 3rd dimension is 6 hourly data and I want daily data, I want to average every 4 data points (i.e. 1:4, 5:8, etc) and end up with a matrix of size 245x85x365.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
R = rand(245,85,1460); % Some random data, same dimensions as your example
szR = size(R);
A = squeeze(mean(reshape(R,[szR(1:2) 4 szR(3)/4]),3)); % Mean across 3rd dimension
```

The [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) function is needed to push the result back down to a three-dimensional array. `A(:,:,1)` from above should be equivalent to `mean(R(:,:,1:4),3)`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use `arrayfun` for this kind of stuff. Lets assume your original data is in `matrix`.

Create a 3-dimensional index vector for `arrayfun` to use:

```
index3d=zeros(1,1,size(matrix,3)/4);
index3d(1,1,:)=(1:size(matrix,3)/4);
```

Use `arrayfun`, unfortunately we must specify `UniformOutput` to be `false` which leads to a cell array as a result.

```
resultcell=arrayfun(@(x) mean(matrix(:,:,4*x-3:4*x), 3), index3d,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Convert cell array to 3-dimensional matrix:

```
result=cell2mat(resultcell);
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your data are stored in the variable old_data and you need a result in new_data, this sample code can be used.

```
new_data=zeros(245,85,365);
for k=0,364
  new_data(:,:, k+1) = sum(old_data(:,:,4*k+1:4*k+4), 3)/4
end
```